# Can't remove field from lightning record page as an admin

Tags: lightning-record-page

I have a lightning app page for object Example__c. I have a field called Example_Field__c on the Example__c object. It was on the 1 and only lightning app page for Example__c, and was removed from the standard page layout (which only has 1 record type).

When I try to remove it from the lightning app page, it's as if I don't have permission to that field. If I click on it, browser shifts to the top of the page. When I try to remove it through the metadata API, it's successful but it's not reflected in the UI.

The way I'm going directly to the record page is by clicking on the record and clicking 'Edit Page'.

It's almost as if I'm not editing the correct lightning record page but that's the only 1 for this object.

Any idea on what could be going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the field marked as Required at the database level - i.e. on the Field itself?

Comment: @PhilW Nope. And when I try to retrieve it back after updating via Metadata API, it's as if it doesn't exist. Yet it's still there in the UI.